# How to store Exception/Error from Azure function js?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

I have created an Azure function to save data in SQL database from Iot Hub that is working fine, Now I want to save Exception and Error to Azure storage Table so for that I have added `try{ } catch(err){}` but that is not working. please correct me. Thanks!

my function is here

```
module.exports = function (context, iotHubMessage) {

try {
    var strMsg = JSON.stringify(iotHubMessage);
    context.log('Message received: ' + strMsg);

    var ob1 = { "employee_idw": 444, "last_name": "Teller", "first_name": "Saara", "age": 34, "salary": 87000 };
    //I misspelled 'employee_idw' to generate error

    var ob2 = { "employee_id": 555, "last_name": "Teller", "first_name": "Saara", "age": 31, "salary": 87000 };

    ob1.EventProcessedUtcTime = new Date;
    ob2.EventProcessedUtcTime = new Date;

    var arr = [];
    arr.push(ob1);
    arr.push(ob2);

    context.bindings.outputTable = arr;


    context.done();
} catch (err) {
    context.log('CCC Error' + err);  // even can not see this message in log
    context.bindings.error= { "partitionKey": partitionKey, "rowKey": rowKey, "data": err };
}
};
```

see this is JSON file

```
{
"bindings": [
 {
  "type": "eventHubTrigger",
  "name": "myEventHubMessage",
  "path": "myeventhub",
  "consumerGroup": "$Default",
  "connection": "PBCorIOTHub_events_IOTHUB",
  "cardinality": "many",
  "direction": "in"
 },
 {
  "type": "apiHubTable",
  "name": "outputTable",
  "dataSetName": "default",
  "tableName": "employees",
  "connection": "sql_SQL",
  "direction": "out"
 },

 {
  "type": "table",
  "name": "error",
  "tableName": "dddtTest",
  "connection": "cccteststr_STORAGE",
  "direction": "out"
 }
 ],
 "disabled": false
 }
```

Comment: Why would misspelled property generate error inside the function? For Table Storage you just need a second output binding, and assign it inside `catch` block.

Comment: ` context.bindings.outputTable = arr` this is my SQL table so I think it will generate error and I wan to save this error  in Azure storage table.

Comment: Why will it generate error? It's an assignment of one JS var to another. Write to SQL happens asynchronously, after the function exits.

Comment: see, I edited my question and it should be error as this is SQL table so it will not found such column 'employee_idw'

Comment: I guess you still miss the point. No interaction with SQL happens inside your function's body. SQL will be called after your `context.done()`, outside of the function. `outputTable` is not a magic DAL class, it's just a property in JS object, which will be used by runtime later.

Comment: yes @Mikhail now I got the point but what is the solution to do such work around ?

Comment: Have you added an [Instrumentation Key](https://dailydotnettips.com/getting-an-application-insights-instrumentation-key-inside-visual-studio-itself/)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Azure SQL or Azure table storage to store the data? From your code it looks like you are using Azure table storage. The reason i ask is because a changed property name would not cause an error in function. Instead the table storage would create a new property with misspelled name.

Like Mikhail suggested the to store an error caused inside of a function all you have to do is create another output binding and assign the exception to it.

However not all exceptions occur inside of a function context. For example an error in function.json configuration could cause a error connecting to storage. This would cause function execution to fail outside of function code context. Azure functions has direct integration with Application Insights and can help monitor what you are looking for. Here is a blog post that can shows how to configure Application Insights.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/04/06/azure-functions-application-insights/

Comment: ` context.bindings.outputTable = arr` this is my SQL table so I think it will generate error and I wan to save this error  in Azure storage table.